# How to access parameters value form url in django decorators

Tags: python, django, python-decorators

I want to make a decorators which prevents the user to see others profile but can see own profile. If the user has id passed in url as http://example.com/user/?id=5 i want to get the value id=5 in my django decorator. How can I get it any example ?

```
def admin_or_ownership_required(owner):
    def check_admin_or_owner(user):
        # pk = request.GET.get('pk', None)
        # if pk is not None and pk == user.id:
        #     return True
        if owner == 'Account':
            if user.is_superuser or (user.is_active and (user.role == 'admin' or user.role == 'owner')):
                return True
            else:
                return False
        elif owner == 'User':
            if user.is_superuser or (user.is_active and (user.role == 'admin' or user.role == 'owner')):
                return True
            else:
                return False
        else:
            return False
    return user_passes_test(check_admin_or_owner)
```

this is my view code

```
class AccountDetailView(DetailView):
    template_name = 'api/account_detail.html'
    model = Account

    @method_decorator(admin_or_ownership_required('Account'))
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(AccountDetailView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

How can I use the request argument in admin_or_ownershipl_required decorator

Comment: There are several ways, please show your view code.

Comment: I have edited my questions with code. I want the code to work exactly as incommented area. But I have no idea how to use get that value of pk.

Answer (score 0):

```
def check_login(method):
   @functools.wraps(method)
   def wrapper(request, *args, **kwargs):
       if request.GET['id'] == request.user.id
           # Give your redirect url
      return method(request, *args, **kwargs)
   return wrapper
```

Comment: can you please answer with respect to my questions

Answer (score 0):

You could use a mixin for your View, where you limit your case queryset, something like:

```
class MixinRestrictedAccount(object):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Account.objects.filter(id=self.request.user.id)


class AccountDetailView(MixinRestrictedBox, DetailView):
    [..]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to dump the value of kwargs, from there you can access the url parameters. for example :
if you have Url like :

```
/users/(?P<username>\w+)/$
```

you can access that value by kwargs parameter , that is passed in your decorator method. You can access that by:

```
kwargs.get("username")
```

If you want to access url parameters by GET method, then you can try like this :

```
request.GET.get("username")
```

for URL's like :

```
/users/?username=dominic
```

Thanks .